# problems evaluating json with karate

Tags: karate

I'm running this feature:

```
* def data = { foo: [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a', bax:[{bav : 's'}] }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' , bax:[{bav : 's'}]}, { bar: 3, baz: 'c', bax:[{bav : 's'}] }]}
* match each data.foo[*].bav == '#number'
```

and it's working.

How is it possible?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, because your JsonPath is wrong. Try:

```
* match each data..bav == '#number'
```

Note that a `match each` on an empty array will always pass.

```
* def temp = []
* match each temp = 'foo'
```